# How to directly infer an image with transforms using fastai?

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

I'm extremely new to fastai and I'm trying to adapt a prior [model](https://github.com/rsomani95/shot-type-classifier). I've been able to load the model and use inference only if the files are on disk. Since I'm trying to process files to a video stream, I'm saving each file and processing them one at a time, eg.

```py
import cv2, imageio 
from fastai.vision import *

# ... load the model here

stream = cv2.VideoCapture('Die.Hard.1988.mkv')

while True:
    _, frame = stream.read()

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg') as FOUT:
        imageio.imwrite(FOUT.name, frame)
        FOUT.flush()

        x = open_image(FOUT.name)
        preds_num = learn.predict(x)[2].numpy()
```

This seems to work, but seems wasteful saving the image to disk. The library seems to use some transforms which means I can't directly push the image to the "learner". Here is how it's loaded:

```
from fastai.vision import *

f_model = "shot-type-classifier"
path = "shot_type_classifier/"

data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(
    path,
    "train",
    "valid",
    size=(375, 666),
    ds_tfms=get_tfms(),
    bs=1,
    resize_method=ResizeMethod.SQUISH,
    num_workers=0,
).normalize(imagenet_stats)

learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=[accuracy], pretrained=True)
learn = learn.to_fp16()
learn.load(f_model)
```

Where the transforms seem to be defined [here](https://github.com/rsomani95/shot-type-classifier/blob/master/initialise.py). I'd really just like to directly pipe images to the preprocesser and then the model without having to save them to disk. Is there a way to do that using fastai?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting frame to a pillow image and then just use pil2tensor:

```
from PIL import Image as PImage
from fastai.vision import *

frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pil_im = PImage.fromarray(frame) 
x = pil2tensor(pil_im ,np.float32)
preds_num = learn.predict(Image(x))[2].numpy()
```

Comment: With this, I'm gettng a `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'apply_tfms'`. I'm assuming that's because the `data` object that I created with the learner has it. I'm really at a loss here on what's going on behind the scenes, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Hooked my bad, forgot to pass the tensor to fastai image. Be careful that both fastai and Pillow export an Image class. Code updated. You could also try just doing Image(frame), it might work too without passing through pillow

Comment: Thanks @juvian your answer helped to solve my inference problem in fastai.